# What command does XAMPP use to start MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

To start a MySQL (technically mariadb) module from the XAMPP control panel, you just click the "Start" action button. What command is being run behind the scenes for "Start"? I've tried to replicate it from the command line with a variety of commands, but I've found that the "Start" button will succeed where my command-line commands fail.

Answer (score 1):

basically

```
mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ammpp\my.ini"
```

`mysqld` is the server command

the `my.ini` ist the configuration you have to check the folder

And MySQL80 is the name

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld.html) for more options

As the github says is the command line in the batch file `xampp/mysql_start.bat` `

```
mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console
```

the my.ini makes some minor changes to the default values, no trickery at all

Comment: This starts -- saying "starting as process 10284 ..." -- but then immediately stops.

Comment: is the my.ini file at that folder specified? i also had a typo

Comment: I got this to work without the "MySQL80". I'm running this from `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` and running `.\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini"` . The `my.ini` file is there and seems to be the same one used when I start from XAMPP control panel.

Comment: on mysql windo 10 x64c 24h2 this will start the start the server

Comment: look at the services and see if it is alredy started

Comment: The last , freestanding (without -- prefix) parameter which is MySQL80, is the windows service name. If you attempt to start that from command line, it will find out that MySQL80 is  an existing service name, attempt a connection to service control manager, and fail that. Basically, if you want to start from command line, omit service name, and if you want some output on the command line, rather than error log file, add --console

Answer (score 1):

The `net start` and `net stop` commands from a command line will start and stop services including of course MySQL or MariaDB.

```
net start mariadb
```

Comment: This gives the message "The requested service has already been started." even though it is not showing up on the XAMPP Control Panel as started. Compare to running `mysqld` -- this causes it to show up in the control panel as started - but only for an instant.

Comment: Chances are good that XAMPP itself turns its flags on and off internally when it issues commands. If you get that message and click start in XAMPP does it work or show as the service already running too?

Answer (score 1):

A modification of nbk's answer worked for me in PowerShell:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --console
```

This shows up as running in the XAMPP Control Panel (v3.2.4) and uses the correct port from the `my.ini` file (I'm using port 3308).

To stop the MySQL server, you can hit Ctrl+C, but only if the MySQL server is open with the `--console` param. To stop it from another terminal I've tried various shutdown commands, but none have worked for me so I've had to use the ugly command:

```
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq mysqld.exe" /T /F
```

From a `.bat` batch file I've also found these commands useful for starting and stopping:

```
:: Start
start "XamppMySQLD1" powershell -NoExit -command "& 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe' --defaults-file='C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini' --console" || echo ERROR && exit /b

:: Is it running? On the expected port?
tasklist | findstr /i "mysql"
netstat -ano | findstr 3308

:: Stop
taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq XamppMySQLD*" /T /F
```

Comment: this is a hard stop you're using. mysql.exe -uroot --password=<your-password> -e shutdown will stop gracefully. If you add --console to the startup command, it will write on the console, not to the error log file, and also you'll be able to stop mysqld with CTRL-C.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub - I've had no luck with any of the shutdown commands. That particular one just says "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server". But excellent point about the `--console` param. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: you probably need the correct port. try mysql.exe --port=3308 -uroot --password=<your-password> -e shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what trickery the XAMPP package uses, but if you want to start the mariadb service from the cmd, all you need is an **elevated** command prompt and the following line:

```sh
net start MariaDB
```

Note: my OS is Win10

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually trying to figure out what the "trickery" XAMPP is using.